# regex for background-image:url('URL');

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I trying to make a regex for finding: background-image:url('URL'); Where the URL is a external link for an image.
Been trying for something like this:

```
 /\s*?[ \t\n]background-image:url('https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$');/i
```

But couldn't get it to work.
I am using this with javascript/jquery

Comment: And what is the source string you are trying to match?

Comment: you also should account for the different ways you can write the css. for example: they might not even use `background-image`. they might use `background: #000 url(..)`  plus, there could be a space in `background-image:<space>url` or they might not even use quotes for their url. `url(http://blah.jpg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get what you want?:

```
/\s*?[ \t\n]background-image:url\('.+?'\);/i
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted for this, so I set it back to 0.  Though I can point out that `.*?` is somewhat an anti-pattern in regex.  It is the leading cause of slowdowns and is the backtracking king.  I might suggest instead using this for the quoted portion: `'[^']*'`.  e.g.: tick, followed greedily and optionally by everything that isn't a tick, then closing tick

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify it to this if you know it will only change with the URL in the middle. I probably went overboard with the \ escapes but better to be safe than sorry.

`/background\-image\:url\(\'.*?\'\)\;/`

Comment: `.*?` is an anti-pattern in regex.  Also, no need to escape a hyphen or semicolon.  Also no need to capture the semicolon to make the regex successful, might actually break it depending on spacing and if they even use a semicolon.  Also, what if they have spaces after the colon?  Or before the colon?  Also, you are capturing local images here, not just external ones.  The OP asked about external images, so you should require http or https in the URL.  The OP didn't provide enough detail, but your answer should at least match the detail he did provide.

Answer (score -1):

Epascarello hit the nail on the head.  Is this source you control?  Or at least a predictable website?  What are multiple different examples of input and your expected results?

Will this always be inline in double quotes, and therefore your URL will always be in single quotes?  Some old websites use double-quotes in their CSS Files or header CSS.

Do you want to capture the whole thing?  Or are you just trying to extract the resulting URL?

SirCapsAlot brings up a good question, are you just looking for background image URL's in general?  Because they can use the Background property also, or even be set in JavaScript with  `.backgroundImage="url(image.jpg)"`.

And you definitely only want the ones that include http(s)?

With the limited requirements you gave, this is the best Regex:

```
background-image\s*:\s*url\('(https?://[^']+)
```

Comment here if you have answers to my questions which may alter your requirements, and thusly my answer.

Breakdown:

```
background-image:\s*url  //Find the literal text to begin
\('                      //Find the literal opening parens and quote
(                        //Begin Capture Group 1
    https?://            //Require the match of https:// (the s is optional because of the ?)
    [^']+                //Require that everything until the next quote is matched
)                        //Capture the result into Group 1
```

A Co-Worker pointed out that I might have been downvoted for not capturing the closing tick.  Note: Capturing the closing tick would be a wasted step, and is not necessary for this regex to work.

He also pointed out somebody might have downvoted me for requiring http or https in the url portion.  But the user's question was specifically for external URLs, not internal ones.  So this is a valid requirement and gets him closer to what he asked.

Sooo... not sure why this got a downvote.